# How to interpret this class diagram and relations?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image: Example diagram]

Hello,

I am learning UML and I am facing some challenges with the class diagram.
My learning sources don't explain the generalization relationship very well and also the abstract class subject (or I don't understand it enough).

When taking this for example. There is a class person with an attribute ' name' with a generalization relationship to ProjectEmployee.

1. I see it as Person is the parent and Projectemployee as the child. So the person is a projectemployee as well?
2. And projectemployee has an aggregation relationship to projectteam. Does this mean that the person is always part of a projectteam?
3. Is it better to make 'person'  an abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This diagram says that `ProjectEmployee` is a specialization of the more general `Person`. In other words, every `ProjectEmployee` is a `Person`, but there may be some `Person` that are not `ProjectEmployee`
2. The (shared) aggregation means the same thing as an ordinary association (at least for the current UML specifications, which do not define its semantics). So it means that `ProjectEmployee` may be associated with a `Projectteam`. We can’t tell more since multiplicities are not specified in this diagram. Only multiplicities can tell you if a team member must or can belong to a team. For example, `1` on the diamond side means that a member must belong to  exactly one team, `1..*` that a member must belong to at least one team but can belong to several teams at the same time.
3. There is no argument here to suggest that `Person` should be abstract. There is no argument for the contrary either. The question is therefore: what would you want to achieve by making it abstract?  For example, do you have some operation that `Person` should offer, but that could only be defined for subclasses and not for a `Person` in general?  Or do you want to prevent `Person` to be instantiated?

Comment: thank you.clear 1. clear. 2. what if there is a 1..* relationship. will that say that Person is always part of a projectteam? or isn't it because of the generalization between person and  projectemployee? 3. what could be a reason to make it abstract class?

Comment: @KeesLasser you're welcome.  I have edited my answer to cover these aspects as well.

Comment: ok. so if there is a 1 at the diamond side it means that a projectemployee is always part of a projectteam but that a person is not always a projectemployee?

Comment: @KeesLasser yes